# When using authentication for solr it does not recognize that it started

Tags: python, solr

I'm working with solr and have recently set up authentication for it. Now everytime I start solr via cmd with:

```
subprocess.call(SOLR_BIN_PATH + '\solr.cmd -p ' + '8983')
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR: Solr at http://localhost:8983/solr did not come online within 30 seconds!
```

It feels like solr does not recognize it started, because it can't authenticate it against the server. Can anyone tell me how to fix this, so that this process call does not take 30 sec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can configure the authentication information to be used](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/basic-authentication-plugin.html#using-the-solr-control-script-with-basic-auth) in the `solr.in.cmd` or `solr.in.sh` script:

> **Using the Solr Control Script with Basic Auth Add the following line**
>
> Add the following line to the solr.in.sh or solr.in.cmd file. This example tells the `bin/solr`
> command line to to use `basic` as the type of authentication, and to
> pass credentials with the user-name `solr` and password `SolrRocks`:
>
> ```
> SOLR_AUTH_TYPE="basic"
> SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS="-Dbasicauth=solr:SolrRocks"
> ```

In the `.cmd` file you have to prefix these lines with `set` - there should already be examples in the `solr.in.cmd` file present, search for `SOLR_AUTH` and you should fine them. Remove `REM` in front of the lines and modify them to have the relevant authentication details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
However, changing the solr.in.cmd file gives me: 
'SOLR_AUTH_TYPE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. 
Changing the solr.in.sh files does nothing at all.

Comment: Should have said it earlier: I'm on solr 8.4.1

Comment: You can't add _just_ `SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS` in the `.cmd` file (that syntax is only valid for the `.sh` file - i.e. when using bash and not cmd); you have to prefix it with `set` - i.e. `set SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS="-Dbasicauth=solr:SolrRocks"`. There should already be examples that you can modify int he file (remove `REM` in front of the line).